# virgin australia 1 PC baggage interpretation

Tags: luggage, virgin-australia

Both my wife and I are flying round trip from Sydney, Australia to Auckland, NZ, round trip.  Our e ticket indicates baggage allowance: 1 pieces.
Does that mean 1 checked bag for EACH of us or 1 checked bag total for both of us?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but would expect the baggage allowance to be per seat, and not per booking. I'd ask Virgin Australia directly: https://www.virginaustralia.com/au/en/help/contact-us/

Comment: I've never seen this mean anything other than 1 per person.

Answer (score 1):

Have flown Virgin trans-Tasman several times. It's definitely per seat (per person).

Virgin's [baggage allowances are listed here](https://www.virginaustralia.com/nz/en/plan/baggage/checked-baggage/), but having also worked for an airline, I can assure you it's per passenger.